# Using HTACCESS to change .html files names into $_GET[] id variables

Tags: html, .htaccess, get

What i want to achieve is :

If there is a url that ends with :

```
_2.html
```

or any other number like :

```
_3.html , _4.html
```

change it to

```
?page_number_0=2
```

example :

```
http://example.com/top-10-answers/top-10-answer_2.html
http://example.com/top-10-answers/top-10-answer_3.html
http://example.com/top-10-answers/top-10-answer_4.html
```

....

to :

```
http://example.com/top-10-answers/?page_number_0=2
http://example.com/top-10-answers/?page_number_0=3
http://example.com/top-10-answers/?page_number_0=4
```

.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+_([0-9]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /top-10-answers/?page_number_0=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

%1 is part of the regex in RewriteCond, it's the part captured between ([ and ]) .

Comment: Thanks Starkeen It works but only for number 2  because the second 
RewriteRule has a static number  :
RewriteRule ^ /top-10-answers/?page_number_0=2 [NC,L,R] 
is there a way for the second rule to be dynamic and to take the above rules number ?

Comment: Or maybe can we make 9 rules for each number from 2 to 10 ?

Comment: @luarbballa No, just 1 rule is enough.

Comment: @Sarkeen it works fully now , but there is one problem , now it opens only the root folder where the .html files are and when i access them 
the rule apply but it doesn't open the files :(